# How to make call of C# function on aspx page.`

Tags: asp.net

I have a function written on a class in c#. This function is returning the image src. 
Now i want to usethis in img tag like this way:

```
<img src=<%=myclass.GetImageUrl('imagename')%> >
```

is it posible in aps.net on aspx pages.

Is there any other waw to call function on a aspx page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code will work fine, as long is the class is `public` and the function is `public static`, and as long as you've imported the namespace in an `<%@ Import %>` directive.

Comment: @Slaks and you have a reference to the namespace

Comment: Why does the method have to be static? The page aka `this` is in scope.

Comment: @leppie: The method is in a different class.

Comment: @SLaks: Perhaps `myClass` is a `protected` member of the page.

Comment: @leppie I think that it's quite obvious that `myClass` is a class and not an object, isn't it? if it really is an object, he should consider naming it better

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: I use all lowercase names for non-public fields and variables. Public names of types and members does get 'proper casing'.

Comment: @leppie i refered to the fact that it had the word `class` in the name

Comment: hi, Thanks for your rply
Bcoz i am using the above code in usercontrols so its giving the error while loading the usercontrol

e:\myproj\UC_GetStarted.ascx(38): error CS1012: Too many characters in character literal
If i used static image path the its loading properly.
it mean that above code is not working?
So can u pls help me how i can load dynamic image paths. Image path wil return from server side code.